# TextContent length doesn't change after DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, cross-browser

I'm seeing strange behaviour in Firefox after DOM manipulation. Changing the content of a TextNode doesn't udpate its properties. E.g. removing a character does not update length of textContent.

Here is the HTML

```
<p>Input:</p>
<div> <span id="cursor"></span></div>
<p>Results:</p>
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

And the JavaScript

```
var cursor = document.getElementById("cursor"),
    result = document.getElementById("result");

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  //Backspace event
  if (e.which == 8) {
    cursor.previousSibling.textContent = cursor.previousSibling.textContent.substring(0, cursor.previousSibling.textContent.length - 1);
  }
}, true);

//Capture key press and write character to TextNode
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  cursor.previousSibling.textContent = cursor.previousSibling.textContent + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
}, true);
```

Test this code at http://jsfiddle.net/dx7Dy/9/

In Chrome it works as expected, as you type the div is filled with letters. Backspace removes the last character.

In Firefox, after the first backspace, the last character is removed, but textContent length of the TextNode is not updated.

I've seen the same problem when removing a TextNode (both *node.remove()*, and *parentNode.removeChild(node)*). Its content is emptied, but the node remains in the DOM, so the next remove() just tries to remove the same empty node, leaving it empty and in place again.

This only happens when triggered via an event listener. If I manipulate the DOM via the Firebug console, for example, everything works as expected.

Is this a bug in the code of Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug in the code, found it while tweaking JSFiddle. The two listeners are interacting.

Chrome does not trigger the keypress event when backspace is pressed. Firefox does.

See it happening here http://jsfiddle.net/dx7Dy/11/ I added the log code to both listeners.

```
result.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<li>"+cursor.previousSibling.textContent + " " + cursor.previousSibling.textContent.length + "</li>");
```